# Yii2 - Checkboxlist Value Store In Database

Tags: yii2, active-form

in my db structure

```
service_request type enum('towel','tissue','napkin')
```

then have a model

```
* @property string $service_request
```

then in my view

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'service_request')->checkBoxList([ 'towel' => 'Towel', 'tissue' => 'Tissue', 'napkin' => 'Napkin']) ?>
```

then when i choose towel, tissue and napkin then submit the form, it's have an error said

> Service Request must be String

please help me

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Joji Thomas said, checkBoxList prodices an array.
You need to change your database structure so that it supports 1-to-many relations (each $model can have multiple *service_request*s) if you want to save this. Unfortunately Yii is not very good at this sort of thing out of the box so you have to do a bunch of things yourself.

First you need to create a `ServiceRequest` ActiveRecord.

Then your `$model` needs to have a relation like:

```
public function getServiceRequests() {
    return $this->hasMany(ServiceRequest::className(), ['model_id' => 'id'];
}
```

Then in your controller (model create action) you will need to do something like this:

```
foreach (Yii::$app->request->post('ServiceRequest',[]) as $data) {
    $item = new ServiceRequest($data);
    $model->link('serviceRequests', $item);
}
```

If you wanna update the checkboxes too then you need to do something similar in your model update action as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please change checkBoxList to radioList, because when selecting multiple values service_request becomes an array. Enum type can handle only string values.

Answer (score 0):

First change your filed datatype from enum to varchar. enum only takes a single string value.
Secondly you need to implode service_request array to string for save to db.
Use bellow code before the model save function :

```
$model->service_request = implode("," , $model->service_request);
$model->save();
```